# How to kill Task Manager in java?

Tags: java, kill-process

In my program I want kill Task Manager if it's running. I've tried this:

```
 private static final String TASKLIST = "tasklist";
private static final String KILL = "taskkill /F /IM ";
if(isProcessRunning("Taskmgr.exe")){
    // TODO code application logic here
    killProcess("Taskmgr.exe");
}
```

Here is my `isProcessRunning()` method:

```
public static boolean isProcessRunning(String servicename) throws Exception {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(TASKLIST);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        if (line.contains(servicename)) {
            System.err.println(line);
            return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
}
```

And the `killprocess()` method:

```
public static void killProcess(String serviceName) throws Exception {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(KILL + serviceName);
}
```

But Task Manager is still running. What can i do?

Comment: What is `KILL` ?

Comment: Have you checked if your program is priviliged to shut down Taskmgr? Also taskmgr is without capital 'T'

Comment: Beyond that: why do you want to do that? That is like the last thing I would want a Java program to do when running it on a windows machine.

Comment: private static final String TASKLIST = "tasklist";
private static final String KILL = "taskkill /F /IM ";

Comment: @alpha_boy Keep in mind that this code is platform dependent and will not work on another system if you happen to try to run it there.

Comment: If you're using Java 9+, you can try using `ProcessHandle`'s API.

Comment: Never put more such code information into comments, update your question instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

okay as to kill taskmanager you need administrator privilage. for this download [this](https://www.winability.com/download/Elevate.zip).

now copy any one file Elevate.exe or Elevate64.exe in your java project source path.

then

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("src//Elevate64.exe TASKKILL /F /IM Taskmgr.exe");
```

now it will prompt for yes or no. click on yes.... and BOOM

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime()
    p.exec("taskkill /F /IM taskmgr.exe /T")
catch(*Enter applicable exception type here*  e){
    System.err.println("Caught Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

It isn't necessary to explicitly check if the task is running.  If it isn't found then the command won't be executed.  Try to kill it and if you get an exception, then account for it in the catch block(s).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the case of the process?
For example:

```
if(isProcessRunning("taskmgr.exe")){
    killProcess("taskmgr.exe");
}
```

Comment: yes the code is correct if i try for another process .

Comment: But taskmgr.exe is without capital

Comment: Doesn't matter in windows.  open a command prompt and test cmd.exe vs Cmd.exe.  returns the same process